# select and concatenate everything before and after a certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I've got a string like `AAAA.BBB.CCCC.DDDD.01.A` and I'm looking to manipulate this and end up with `AAAA-BBB`

I've achieved this by writing this debatable piece of code

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'AAAA.BBB.CCCC.DDDD.01.A'
select replace(substring(@string,0,charindex('.',@string)) + substring(@string,charindex('.',@string,CHARINDEX('.',@string)),charindex('.',@string,CHARINDEX('.',@string)+1)-charindex('.',@string)),'.','-')
```

Is there any other way to achieve this which is more elegant and readable ?

I was looking at some `string_split` operations, but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: No, not in SQL Server.

Comment: I was hoping for something similar to `split_part` in postgresql, but thank you.

Comment: So you want everything before the first . combined with everything  after the first . and before the second . with a - separating them?

Comment: yes, running that piece of code will output the expected result.

Comment: @madlicksxxx , also, are the lengths of the individual sections the same ever time?

Comment: no, the lengths can come in different shapes and sizes

Comment: What is ypour SQL Server version?

Comment: it's sql server 2017

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little cleaner:

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'AAAA.BBB.CCCC.DDDD.01.A'
select 
  replace( -- replace '.' with '-' (A)
      substring(@string, 1 -- in the substring of @string starting at 1 
          ,charindex('.', @string -- and going through 1 before the index of '.'(B)
            ,charindex('.',@string)+1) -- that is after the first index of the first '.' 
           -1) -- (B)
    ,'.','-') -- (A)
```

Comment: This would be my choice

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to some `JSON` transformations, the following approach is an option. You need to transform the text into a valid JSON array (`AAAA.BBB.CCCC.DDDD.01.A` is transformed into `["AAAA","BBB","CCCC","DDDD","01","A"]`) and get the required items from this array using `JSON_VALUE()`:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'AAAA.BBB.CCCC.DDDD.01.A'
SET @string = CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@string, '.', '","'), '"]')
SELECT CONCAT(JSON_VALUE(@string, '$[0]'), '-', JSON_VALUE(@string, '$[1]'))
```

Result:

```
AAAA-BBB
```

Notes: With this approach you can easily access all parts from the input string by index (0-based).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is in your string you might be able to abuse PARSENAME into doing it. Intended for breaking up names like `adventureworks.dbo.mytable.mycolumn` it works like this:

```
DECLARE @x as VARCHAR(100) = 'aaaa.bbb.cccc.ddddd'

SELECT CONCAT( PARSENAME(@x,4), '-', PARSENAME(@x,3) )
```

You could also look at a mix of STUFF to delete the first '.' and replace with '-' then LEFT the result by the index of the next '.' but it's unlikely to be neater than this or Kevin's proposal 
Using string split would likely be as unwieldy:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN v END), '-', MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN v END)) 
FROM (
  SELECT row_number () over (order by (select 0)) rn, value as v 
  FROM string_split(@x,'.')
) y WHERE rn IN (1,2)
```

Because the string is split to rows which then need to be numbered in order to filter and pull the parts you want. This also relies on the strings coming out of string split in the order they were in the original string, *which MS do not guarantee will be the case*

Comment: That was my first thought too, but doesn't work if there are more than 3 dots

Comment: Using `STRING_SPLIT()` is dangerous, because, as is mentioned in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) _The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string._

Comment: That is also true, I'll make a note